# What is the meaning of 'Here a “that,” there a “that,” everywhere a “that-that”'?

Tags: poetry

> Here a “that,” there a “that,” everywhere a “that-that”

Is it correctly in grammar?
I suppose it means

> Here is a “that,” there is a “that,” everywhere is a “that-that”.

is my sentence better?

Comment: Your sentence is correct, not better. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_MacDonald_Had_a_Farm

Comment: Thank you.I wonder if **be** could be omitted between **here** and  **noun**? is **here** a noun or a adverb in this sentence?

Comment: We don't omit the predicate in conversation. We don't say "Here where you will sleep but "Here's where you will sleep".  What is idiomatic in a song lyric or ditty may not be idiomatic in speech.

Comment: That said, in certain non-conversational speech contexts the predicate can be dropped. For example, speaking before an audience, say, with an image projected onto a screen: "On the left, the lungs of a  heavy smoker. And here, on the right, a pair of healthy lungs."

Comment: When saying these quotes, would you say the word "that"?  Or would you replace the word "that" with something else, like "moo" or "cow"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line comes from the children's song, *Old MacDonald Had a Farm*

> Old MACDONALD had a farm, E-I-E-I-O
>   And on his farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O
>   With a moo moo here
>   And a moo moo there
>   **Here a moo, there a moo**
>   **Everywhere a moo moo**
>   Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O
>
> http://www.kidsongs.com/lyrics/old-macdonald-had-a-farm.html

If you use that construct, every reader/listener who grew up on that nursery song will recognize it.  If you correct it, but do not significantly change the pattern (i.e. Here a blank, there a blank, everywhere a blank-blank), then it will be awkward to the reader/listener.

Unless you have good reason to change it, use the original form.  However be mindful that the form is an allusion to the nursery rhyme, so it may not be appropriate for professional communication.  Unless, that is, you purposefully wish to evoke a child-like tone for some sort of effect such as humor.